# VBA Combo Box in Excel for Search Engine Invalid property-array index (Error 381)

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Additional Information.

The vba code is the search engine, purpose of taking the list of customers details (name) on the other sheet which i filter with formula.

This is the background data worksheets.
[Worksheets "background data"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgDNF.png)
Was filter by using by value i enter on the combo box.

It works on the combo box,
[This is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dhch.png)
But when i click on any customer name,
the error below pop up.

I have problem on vba code in excel

can you guys help me how to fix this error.

Invalid property-array index (Error 381)

[image: THIS IS THE ERROR PICTURE]

```
Option Explicit

 Private Comb_Arrow As Boolean

 Private Sub search_engine_Change()
 Dim i As Long

    If Not Comb_Arrow Then
    With Me.search_engine
       .list = Worksheets("BACKGROUND DATA").Range("B2", Worksheets("BACKGROUND DATA").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)).Value
       .ListRows = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(4, .ListCount)
       .DropDown
           If Len(.Text) Then
                For i = .ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
                   If InStr(1, .list(i), .Text, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then .RemoveItem i
                     Next
                      .DropDown
                       End If
     End With
     End If

End Sub


Private Sub search_engine_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    Comb_Arrow = (KeyCode = vbKeyUp) Or (KeyCode = vbKeyDown)
    If KeyCode = vbKeyReturn Then Me.search_engine.list = Worksheets("BACKGROUND DATA").Range _
    ("B2", Worksheets("BACKGROUND DATA").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)).Value
End Sub
```

Comment: To debug this we'll need to know exactly which line causes the error, and the values of your variables at the time of the error

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub search_engine_Change()
Dim i, LRow As Long
LRow = Worksheets("BACKGROUND DATA").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
If LRow > 1 Then
    If Not Comb_Arrow Then
    With Me.search_engine
       .List = Worksheets("BACKGROUND DATA").Range("B1", Worksheets("BACKGROUND DATA").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)).Value
       .RemoveItem 0
       .ListRows = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(4, .ListCount)
       '.DropDown
           If Len(.Text) Then
                For i = .ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
                   If InStr(1, .List(i), .Text, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then .RemoveItem i
                     Next
                     ' .DropDown
                       End If
     End With
     End If
End If
End Sub
Private Sub search_engine_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    Comb_Arrow = (KeyCode = vbKeyUp) Or (KeyCode = vbKeyDown)
    If KeyCode = vbKeyReturn Then Me.search_engine.List = Worksheets("BACKGROUND DATA").Range _
    ("B1", Worksheets("BACKGROUND DATA").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)).Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Please, add some explanation about how you think your answer solves the issue.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read How to Answer and edit your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

The problem lies in this line:

```
.list = Worksheets("BACKGROUND DATA").Range("B2", Worksheets("BACKGROUND DATA").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)).Value
```

The range object only takes a single argument, you are trying to send it 2. If you are looking to have a multi cell range, such as B2:B5, then you cannot take a value of that range, as it will have multiple values.  All around this line appears to have multiple problems.

If you provide more data as to what you are trying to achieve, it will be of further help.  What are you trying to achieve with the second argument?  What value are you looking for?

Comment: hi thanks for the answer. I just add some more information above, when change the range it still happen.

Comment: What did you change it to?  Did you get the same error?

Comment: You will need to do a bit more then just changing the range. The way you are using the range object is incorrect.  Your range object is such:

Range("B2", Worksheets("BACKGROUND DATA").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))

The comma after "B2" denotes a second arguemnt you are sending to the Range object.  It can only take one argument.
Also, the Cells Object, only takes number, you cannot send it text, "B".  You must refer to Column B as column 2.

Comment: From what you described I believe you are trying to make a range from B2:End of Columm B. If that is true then the list line would look someting like this:

.list = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:B" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row)

If that is not what you are trying to then, then you need to explain the sheet and your desired action better.